# C: Most efficient way to determine how many bytes will be needed for a UTF-16 string from a UTF-8 string

Tags: c, algorithm, utf-8, utf-16, unicode-string

I've seen some very clever code out there for converting between Unicode codepoints and UTF-8 so I was wondering if anybody has (or would enjoy devising) this.

- Given a UTF-8 string, how many bytes are needed for the UTF-16 encoding of the same string.
- Assume the UTF-8 string has already been validated. It has no BOM, no overlong sequences, no invalid sequences, is null-terminated. It is not [CESU-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CESU-8).
- Full UTF-16 with surrogates must be supported.

Specifically I wonder if there are shortcuts to knowing when a surrogate pair will be needed without fully converting the UTF-8 sequence into a codepoint.

The best UTF-8 to codepoint code I've seen uses vectorizing techniques so I wonder if that's also possible here.

Comment: Does "no invalid sequences" include "no surrogate values encoded in UTF-8"?

Comment: @Joachim: Yes. "It is not CESU-8".

Comment: ah, I see, I wasn't aware of that term.

Comment: @Karl: Because I wanted a low-level C solution ideally. I wanted to encourage pointers over calls to system functions. Especially I wanted something akin to this: http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2008-06-05-faster-utf8-strlen.html (but discussion of other languages or language-independent ideas is welcome too)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Efficiency is always a speed vs size tradeoff. If speed is favored over size then the most efficient way is just to guess based on the length of the source string.

There are 4 cases that need to be considered, simply take the worst case as the final buffer size:

- U+0000-U+007F - will encode to 1byte in utf8, and 2bytes per character in utf16. (1:2 = x2)
- U+0080-U+07FF - encoded to 2byte utf8 sequences, or 2byte per character utf16 characters. (2:2 = x1)
- U+0800-U+FFFF - are stored as 3byte utf8 sequences, but still fit in single utf16 characters. (3:2 = x.67)
- U+10000-U+10FFFF - are stored as 4byte utf8 sequences, or surrogate pairs in utf16. (4:4 = x1)

The worse case expansion factor is when translating U+0000-U+007f from utf8 to utf16: the buffer, bytewise, merely has to be twice as large as the source string. Every other unicode codepoint results in an equal size, or smaller bytewise allocation when encoded as utf16 as utf8.

Comment: "most efficient" depends a lot on how the priorities of calculation cost vs. memory cost are set, but I agree: in general this most likely the best approach.

Comment: I had thought of this but didn't fully analyse it. Now that you have it does indeed seem utterly simple. Thanks!

Comment: I put off accepting your answer because I was hoping somebody might come up with a clever vectorized algorithm. Your approach is obviously unbeatable time-wise but has a worst case of using close to double the amount of memory for languages which don't use many characters beyond ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

Very simple: count the number of head bytes, double-counting bytes `F0` and up.

In code:

```
size_t count(unsigned char *s)
{
    size_t l;
    for (l=0; *s; s++) l+=(*s-0x80U>=0x40)+(*s>=0xf0);
    return l;
}
```

Note: This function returns the length in UTF-16 code units. If you want the number of bytes needed, multiply by 2. If you're going to store a null terminator you'll also need to account for space for that (one extra code unit/two extra bytes).

Comment: +1: I don't think your code is simple, but it is _very_ concise and when I used paper to examine your bit manipulation, it all seemed to be correct. There is only one pedantic mistake. Your function returns the number of 16-bit code units rather than the number of bytes (which is what the question asked for). Returning `l * 2` would fix that.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't notice OP had asked for bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not an algorithm, but if I understand correctly the rules are as such:

- every byte having a MSB of `0` adds 2 bytes (1 UTF-16 code unit)

  - that byte represents a single Unicode codepoint in the range U+0000 - U+007F
- every byte having the MSBs `110` or `1110` adds 2 bytes (1 UTF-16 code unit)

  - these bytes start 2- and 3-byte sequences respectively which represent Unicode codepoints in the range U+0080 - U+FFFF
- every byte having the 4 MSB set (i.e. starting with `1111`) adds 4 bytes (2 UTF-16 code units)

  - these bytes start 4-byte sequences which cover "the rest" of the Unicode range, which can be represented with a low and high surrogate in UTF-16
- every other byte (i.e. those starting with `10`) can be skipped

  - these bytes are already counted with the others.

I'm not a C expert, but this looks easily vectorizable.

Comment: It looks good but you mention "5- or 6-byte sequences" which were removed from legal UTF-8 some years ago and you don't mention 4-byte sequences.

Comment: The missing 4 was a typo (it should have been grouped with the 5s and 6s) and the fact that 5/6-byte sequences aren't allowed any more doesn't really change the algorithm: they are simply grouped in with the 4-byte sequences and would produce the same result anyway. (i.e. I replace "5- or 6-byte" with "4-byte" ;-))

Comment: Aha it looks like the Unicode range >= `U+10000` is indeed exactly the start of both the UTF-8 4-byte range and the `Supplementary Plane`s which is what the surrogates cover. A perfect shortcut (-: