# How to calculate byte length containing UTF8 characters using javascript?

Tags: javascript, utf-8

I have textbox, in which the user can enter the characters in ASCII/UTF-8 or a combination of both. Is there any API in javascript which we can calculate the length of string in bytes for the characters entered in textbox.

Like if i enter ascii chacter let's say : mystring - the length would be calculated as 8. But when UTF8 characters are entered the characters can be 2/3/4 byte.

lets say the character entered : i ♥ u , the length in bytes is 5.

**The textbox can accept max length of 31 characters.** But in case if UTF8 characters entered, it will not accept character string : i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u . the length is 30.

Can we restrict the user to enter characters not more than 31 even for UTF8 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Counting UTF8 bytes comes up quite a bit in JavaScript, a bit of looking around and you'll find a number of libraries (here's one example: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/utf8.js) that can help. I also found a thread (https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/1010324) full of solutions specifically for utf8 byte counts.

Here is the smallest, and most accurate function out of that thread:

```
function countUtf8Bytes(s){
    var b = 0, i = 0, c
    for(;c=s.charCodeAt(i++);b+=c>>11?3:c>>7?2:1);
    return b
}
```

*Note*: I rearranged it a bit so that the signature is easier to read. However its still a very compact function that might be hard to understand for some.

You can check its results with this tool: https://mothereff.in/byte-counter

One correction to your OP, the example string you provided `i ♥ u` is actually 7 bytes, this function does count it correctly.

Comment: This code seems to give 6 for "", but the correct result is 4 I think.

Comment: @recursive because charCodeAt returns 0-65535 only. code points not in BMP(for example, emojis) will be represented as UTF-16 surrogate pairs. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419167/how-to-convert-one-emoji-character-to-unicode-codepoint-number-in-javascript for details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728045/c-most-efficient-way-to-determine-how-many-bytes-will-be-needed-for-a-utf-16-st

Answer (score 27):

As of 2018, the most compatible and reliable way of doing this seems to be with the blob api.

```
new Blob([str]).size
```

[Even supported in IE10](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) if anyone uses that anymore.

Answer (score 5):

The experimental [TextEncoder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) can be used for this but is not supported by Internet Explorer or Safari:

```js
(new TextEncoder()).encode("i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u").length;
```

Another alternative is to URI-encode the string and count characters and %-encoded escape sequences, as in [this library](https://github.com/substack/utf8-length/blob/master/index.js):

```js
~-encodeURI("i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u i ♥ u").split(/%..|./).length
```

The github page has a compatibility list which unfortunately does not include IE10, but IE9.

Since I can not yet comment, I'll also note here that the solution in the accepted answer does not work for code points consisting of multiple UTF-16 code units.