# How to convert one emoji character to Unicode codepoint number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, emoji, emojione

how to convert this  into this `1f600` in **javascript**

```
''.charCodeAt(0);
```

this will return unicode 55357 but how to get 1f600 from

Comment: This npm package has method to convert into Unicode.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-unicode

Comment: @gurvinder372 i already tried your solution it is not working. This is not duplicate question

Comment: @MitulGedeeya how to do it in browser ??

Comment: @ParthGajjar Share what you tried in the question itself so that we know what you have already tried. Create a working snippet demonstrating the issue itself.

Comment: Sorry it will be server side rendering. :) let me give you answer with the function

Comment: @MitulGedeeya used same code and converted for browser side Thanks :)

Comment: okay and you also can try my answer below.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Added script to convert this on browser side

```
function emojiUnicode (emoji) {
    var comp;
    if (emoji.length === 1) {
        comp = emoji.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    comp = (
        (emoji.charCodeAt(0) - 0xD800) * 0x400
      + (emoji.charCodeAt(1) - 0xDC00) + 0x10000
    );
    if (comp < 0) {
        comp = emoji.charCodeAt(0);
    }
    return comp.toString("16");
};
emojiUnicode(""); # result "1f600"
```

thanks to https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-unicode

Comment: That's wrong. When you removed the `returns` from the original function and didn't add the proper `ifs` and `elses` you altered the function. Correct would be how it is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/IonicaBizau/emoji-unicode/c6e9b4f4cfb4546a71aa93ea59dd0f38c057c9f3/lib/index.js

Comment: What about emojis that are a combination of two others and have charCodeAt from 0 to 4? E.g.: ‍♀️

Comment: (Javascript), 
In case you need to convert it back to Emoji again use:
String.fromCodePoint(parseInt ("1f600", 16))

Comment: Country flag doesn't render properly

Comment: @Parth Gajjar: sir can you tell me how to get get emoji from \uD83D\uDE0A
this string?

Comment: Simple Heart '♥' returns NaN

Comment: Is there a way to type a string using this value? Unicode are expected to be 4 digits and emojis got 5 so I can't manually type "\u12345" and get an emoji, since "\u1234" is already a character. See this related issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19557026/how-to-display-5-digit-unicode-characters-such-as-a-speaker-u1f50a
Text editors will display the emoji but it's confusing not to be able to "see" the underlying raw values

Comment: If I go on this site https://emojiterra.com/fr/antenne-satellite/, for JavaScript, I'll get "\uD83D\uDCE1" for a satellite emoji, so 2 4-digit value and not 1 5-digit value. How can I obtain this value?

Answer (score 41):

Two way

```js
let hex = "".codePointAt(0).toString(16)
let emo = String.fromCodePoint("0x"+hex);

console.log(hex, emo);
```

Comment: Really appreciate having the reverse function here!

Comment: \uD83D\uDE0A sir i need to convert mentioned uniquecode to emoji?

Comment: @Kapilsoni try `console.log( String.fromCodePoint("0xD83D","0xDE0A") )` (I get this:  - but if I change sequence of this 2 strings I get �� , if I join strings to "0xD83DDE0A" I get exception

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski:sir my case unicode string is \uD83D\uDE0A.if directly put \uD83D\uDE0A in fromCodePoint its not working.can i convert in any another format?

Comment: @AndreasM. ofcourse, however OP needs hex in question

Answer (score 12):

This is what I use:

```
const toUni = function (str) {
  if (str.length < 4)
    return str.codePointAt(0).toString(16);
  return str.codePointAt(0).toString(16) + '-' + str.codePointAt(2).toString(16);
};
```

Comment: It seems to me this Proso (provider of solution) has the right idea. According to Mozilla https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt codePointAt is specifically for handling emojis or icons.

Comment:  My experimentation indicates you do not need the toString(16). 
If the emoji is 2 chars long (s.length >1), then the 0 position codePointAt(0), renders up the dec needed for html display.

Comment: My mistake, the toString(16) is get the Hex value.

Answer (score 5):

Please Read [This Link](https://medium.com/reactnative/emojis-in-javascript-f693d0eb79fb).

Here is the function :

```
function toUTF16(codePoint) {
var TEN_BITS = parseInt('1111111111', 2);
function u(codeUnit) {
  return '\\u'+codeUnit.toString(16).toUpperCase();
}

if (codePoint <= 0xFFFF) {
  return u(codePoint);
}
codePoint -= 0x10000;

// Shift right to get to most significant 10 bits
var leadSurrogate = 0xD800 + (codePoint >> 10);

// Mask to get least significant 10 bits
var tailSurrogate = 0xDC00 + (codePoint & TEN_BITS);

 return u(leadSurrogate) + u(tailSurrogate);
}
```

Comment: Best solution if you want to get it working in RESP API using json. It give output like "\uD83D\uDE00" (for )

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way. [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt)

```
 "".codePointAt(0).toString(16)
```

Comment: Great answer, combine that with this data source: https://github.com/iamcal/emoji-data/blob/master/emoji.json and you get a great way to convert emojis to shortcuts

Answer (score 3):

Emojis like ‍⚕️ have two parts:  +⚕️.
Here is how to get their code:

```js
emoji = "‍⚕️" // corresponds to  1f469-200d-2695-fe0f
code1 = emoji.codePointAt(0).toString(16) // gives only 1f469
code2 = [...emoji].map(e => e.codePointAt(0).toString(16)).join(`-`) // gives correctly 1f469-200d-2695-fe0f
console.log(code1)
console.log(code2)
```

Comment: `emoji_code = "-".join(f"{ord(c):x}" for c in "‍⚕️")` would be the corresponding implementation in python.

Answer (score 0):

```
const 
  getUnicodeHex = char => char.codePointAt(0).toString(16),    
  getEmoji = unicodeHex => String.fromCodePoint(unicodeHex)

console.log(
  getUnicodeHex(''),  // 1f600
  getEmoji(0x1f600)     // 
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Best answer in my view is to use node-emoji package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-emoji

Here are steps.

1. do npm i node-emoji

   ```
   var emoji = require('node-emoji');
   var convertEmoji = function(data){
   if(emoji.hasEmoji(data)){
       return emoji.unemojify(data);
     }
     else{
        return data;
     }
   }
   ```