# How to get this emoji's dec representation using native js?

Tags: javascript, emoji

I have added an emoji  into html code having written its dec representation inside a div - " &#128512 ";
How do I get the numeral presentation of this emoji?

I need to process a string containing both - text and emojis and the emoji should be represented in numeral view.
So , if I have a string containing - **"hello world "** , it should be replaced to **"hello world &#128512 ;"**

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
if(document.readyState == "complete"){
       document.getElementById("area").addEventListener("keypress" ,      public_mode);
   }
}

function public_mode(event){
    var key = event.key;
  if(key === "Enter") {
     event.preventDefault();
     sendMessage(this);
   }
}

function sendMessage(area){
    console.log(area.innerHTML);
    area.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
#area {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 170px;
    border:1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div id = "area" contenteditable="true">How to get it in dec - &#128512;</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dec view"?

Comment: From context, he means the decimal html entity.

Comment: @NicoHaase , I've just edited the post.It should be more understandable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert one emoji character to Unicode codepoint number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419167/how-to-convert-one-emoji-character-to-unicode-codepoint-number-in-javascript)

Comment: @chevybow , ok,I've solved out how to parse an emoji but how to find it if I have three alphabets in a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the number of a character by [`.codePointAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt):

```js
console.log(`&#${ ("".codePointAt(0)) };`)
```

This (combined with a loop) can solve your problem:

```js
function encodeEmoji(str){
    let output = ""
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
        const codePoint = str.codePointAt(i)
        //don't encode common characters
        if(codePoint > 9727)
            output += `&#${ codePoint };`
        else
            output += str[i]
    }
    return output
}

 console.log(encodeEmoji("hello world "))
```

Comment: This does not fit on account of a string can content russian chars and ukrainian. So , the chars will be represented in numeral view.

Comment: @Sckoriy Ok, then you can modify the 'accepted' charcode range in the if condition. Additionally, characters encoded with this will show as normal if displayed as HTML

Comment: @Sckoriy I've edited my answer accordingly. Now it only converts emojies... Take a look at it!

Comment: as an idea , I can not check if the value is an emoji.I've decided I will get whole string and process it by encode.It doesn't really matter how the content will be saved in a database.

Comment: @Sckoriy I've done a little research, and found the emoji range: chars>9727 are emojies...

Comment: @FZs: i have to convert \uD83D\uDE0A to 128512 this format.can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [codePointAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/codePointAt) (returns a non-negative integer that is the Unicode code point value).

```
let emoji = area.innerHTML.split('- ')[1];
console.log(emoji.codePointAt(0));
```