# How to replace all emoji in string to unicode JS

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, emoji

I have a problem with replace emoji in string to string with unicode.

For example:

I have string:
`const str = "My string  is with emoji "`

I need to convert this string to 
`const str = "My string EMOJI UNICODE is with emoji EMOJI UNICODE"`

emoji unicode should look like : [e-1f60e]. Because I have function for converting string with unicode to string with emoji:

```
function convertEmoji(str) {
  return str.replace(/\[e-([0-9a-fA-F]+)\]/g, (match, hex) =>
    String.fromCodePoint(Number.parseInt(hex, 16))
  );
}

console.log(convertEmoji('string [e-1f60e] sadfsadfsadf'));  // "string  sadfsadfsadf"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `replace` as you do in your function going the other way. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45138005/157247) provides a regex for modern JavaScript that matches various "emoji" ranges. Then in the callback you can use `codePointAt` to get the value of the code point of the emoji, convert it to hex via `toString(16)`, and return a string in your desired format:

```js
const str = "My string  is with emoji "
const rex = /[\u{1f300}-\u{1f5ff}\u{1f900}-\u{1f9ff}\u{1f600}-\u{1f64f}\u{1f680}-\u{1f6ff}\u{2600}-\u{26ff}\u{2700}-\u{27bf}\u{1f1e6}-\u{1f1ff}\u{1f191}-\u{1f251}\u{1f004}\u{1f0cf}\u{1f170}-\u{1f171}\u{1f17e}-\u{1f17f}\u{1f18e}\u{3030}\u{2b50}\u{2b55}\u{2934}-\u{2935}\u{2b05}-\u{2b07}\u{2b1b}-\u{2b1c}\u{3297}\u{3299}\u{303d}\u{00a9}\u{00ae}\u{2122}\u{23f3}\u{24c2}\u{23e9}-\u{23ef}\u{25b6}\u{23f8}-\u{23fa}]/ug;
const updated = str.replace(rex, match => `[e-${match.codePointAt(0).toString(16)}]`);
console.log(updated);
```

See [Wiktor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59918364/157247) as well. ES2018 adds Unicode property escapes. But unfortunately, support is still spotty, though the one he uses in his answer works in Chromium and its derivatives (Chrome, Brave, Chromium Edge) and iOS Safari, though sadly not yet in Firefox.

Comment: If anyone wants to do any testing, or create an even better regex themselves, [this](http://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.0/) a good thing to look at. (For possible future viewers, don't look at this outdated emoji 12.0 version, Google what the latest version is)

Answer (score 5):

If you target ECMAScript 2018 and newer, you may use

```
/\p{Emoji}/ug
```

JS demo:

```js
const str = "My string  is with emoji ";
console.log(
  str.replace(/\p{Emoji}/ug, (m, idx) =>
   `[e-${m.codePointAt(0).toString(16)}]`
  )
);
```

Comment: This will work someday. :-) For now, sadly, Unicode property escapes are not well-supported. Even the latest Firefox doesn't handle this yet. Very pleased to see support in iOS Safari and Chrome/Chromium/Brave/ChromiumEdge though.

Comment: Non-Chromium Edge doesn't support them (took a minute to test it). Fortunately that problem will solve itself soon. :-)

Comment: Just in case, you may also check [Can I use *Unicode property escapes (`\p{...}`)*](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_regexp_property_escapes)

Comment: Interestingly, that information is incorrect for Edge 79, which does support them. I'll see if I can do a PR.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is, start with `Array.from()`:

```
Array.from("My string  is with emoji ")
```

This will give you the separate characters into an array:

```
["M", "y", " ", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", " ", "", " ", "i", "s", " ", "w", "i", "t", "h", " ", "e", "m", "o", "j", "i", " ", ""]
```

Here, you can use the `charCode` function to check if the current item is an emoji and apply your custom function using the `.map()`.

Check out [How to convert one emoji character to Unicode codepoint number in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48419167) for the initial conversion and use the `Array.map()` function to do the mapping and finally convert the array into string using `.join("")`.

> ***Note:*** I have explained the process of converting so that the OP can go ahead and try it out, and I intentionally didn't think of spoon-feeding the OP with the complete solution, even though I have got one, tried and tested.

Comment: Don't use `charCodeAt`, it returns code *units*, not code *points*. Use `codePointAt`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Didn't know something like that exists...